# Dataframe sort future warning - trying to sort by sort_values()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called OutputDf that looks like:

```
            Date  Last Price           Type
1928  02/07/2010        0.00  missing value
1952  31/05/2010         NaN  missing value
1972  03/05/2010         NaN  missing value
2048  13/01/2010        0.00  missing value
659   10/06/2015      402.70        outlier
1020  13/01/2014      471.15        outlier
1309  23/11/2012      492.14        outlier
1698  26/05/2011      404.99        outlier
2057  30/12/2009      476.86        outlier
```

I am sorting the dataframe by the `Date` field using:

```
OutputDf = OutputDf.ix[pd.to_datetime(OutputDf.Date).order().index]
```

However I am getting future warning:

```
FutureWarning: order is deprecated, use sort_values(...)
```

I have tried to change to using sort_values() as suggested by implementing:

```
OutputDf = OutputDf.sort_values("Date", ascending = True, 
                 inplace = True)
```

but I get `None` returned.

The desired output will be sorted by date (ascending) and would look like:

```
              Date  Last Price            Type
2057    30/12/2009      476.86         outlier
2048    13/01/2010           0  missing values
1972    03/05/2010         NaN  missing values
1952    31/05/2010         NaN  missing values
1928    02/07/2010           0  missing values
1698    26/05/2011      404.99         outlier
1309    23/11/2012      492.14         outlier
1020    13/01/2014      471.15         outlier
659     10/06/2015       402.7         outlier
```

How can I implement sort_values correctly?

Comment: Well, yeah, you used `inplace=True` _and_ did a reassignment back to the same name. Pick one, but don't use both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
OutputDf = OutputDf.sort_values("Date", ascending = True, 
             inplace = True)
```

When you're setting the parameter inplace=True, it's making the changes on the actual object that's calling the function, and it returns **None**.

So basically what you're doing is, you're sorting your dataframe, and then initializing the return value of None back to itself.

You can fix this by removing `inplace=True`